# Count query giving wrong column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select  COUNT(analysed) from Results where analysed="True"
```

I want to display count of rows in which analysed value is true.

However, my query gives the error: "The multi-part identifier "Results.runId" could not be bound.".

This is the actual query:

```
select ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True')/failCount) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs 
where Runs.runId=Analysed.runId
```

My table schema is:

[image]

[image: The Analysed table schema is:]

[image: Results table schema]

The value I want for a particular runId is: (the number of entries where analysed=true)/failCount

**EDIT** : How to merge these two queries?

i) select runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,totalCount as TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent,
            passCount,failCount,runOwner from Runs,Product where Runs.prodId=Product.prodId

ii) select (cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs 
inner join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True'
  GROUP BY runId
) counts
on counts.runId = Runs.runId

I tried this :
select runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,totalCount as TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent,
            passCount,failCount,runOwner,counts.runId,(cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs,Product 
inner join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True'
  GROUP BY runId
) counts
on counts.runId = Runs.runId
where Runs.prodId=Product.prodId

but it gives error.

Comment: select COUNT(analysed) from Results where analysed=True don't give "True"

Comment: What data type is the `analysed` column? If it's a BIT field then `select COUNT(analysed) from Results where analysed=1` should work since when setting a BIT field, use `0` for `'False'` and `1` for `'True'`. Note that there are no quotes around the `0` or `1`. If it's a varchar then single quotes will work `select COUNT(*) as [Count] from Results
where analysed = 'True'`

Comment: Single quotes should work fine.

Comment: @chridam - `select CAST('True' AS BIT),  CAST('False' AS BIT)` both work fine.

Comment: The inner query (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True') works but not the whole thing

Comment: @user1698232 You have included a definition of a "runs" table (and I can see that you have left off some of its columns), but not a "results" table. Please add that schema. The runs table has no column named "Analysed" and this is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Oh,yes.I'll add that

Comment: @user1698232 Please ask a new question about the new queries, rather than adding them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are arising from improper joining of tables. You need information from both Runs and Results, but they aren't combined properly in your query. You have the right idea with a nested subquery, but it's in the wrong spot. You're also referencing the Analysed table in the outer where clause, but it hasn't been included in the from clause.

Try this instead:

```
select (cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs 
inner join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True'
  GROUP BY runId
) counts
on counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

I've set this up as an inner join to eliminate any runs which don't have analysed results; you can change it to a left join if you want those rows, but will need to add code to handle the null case. I've also added casts to the two numbers, because otherwise the query will perform integer division and truncate any fractional amounts.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'resultId'.

Comment: I think its because the resultId in your query is ambiguous.Doesn't say which table.I tried Results.resultId but still doesn't work

Comment: The column name isn't ambiguous, it's simply wrong: I typed **result**Id when it should be **run**Id. Your runs table does not have resultId as a column. I have fixed my code.

Comment: select runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,totalCount as TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent,
            passCount,failCount,runOwner from Runs,Product where Runs.prodId=Product.prodId

Comment: This is one query I have.And yours is another to add the column "PercentAnalysed". How do merge these two queries to form a single one ?

Comment: I tried this : select runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,totalCount as TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent,
            passCount,failCount,runOwner,counts.runId,(cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs,Product 
inner join
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId 
  FROM Results 
  WHERE Analysed = 'True'
  GROUP BY runId
) counts
on counts.runId = Runs.runId  
where Runs.prodId=Product.prodId

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM Results
WHERE Analysed = 'True'
```

This will count all of your rows where Analysed is `'True'`. This should work if the datatype of your `Analysed` column is either BIT (Boolean) or STRING(VARCHAR, NVARCHAR).

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` in `Count`

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN analysed='True' THEN analysed END) [COUNT]
FROM Results
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c901/1) to view result

Comment: If he already filters the rows based on `analysed='True'` condition, he won't have to go over the entire result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  COUNT(*) from Results where analysed="True"
```